# Arithmetical operations on equations symbolicaly in R without yacas

Tags: r, math, equation, symbolic-math

*I have equations defined like`f<-"x^2"`and `g<-"y^2"`. I want to obtain equation z like `z<-(x^2)*(y^2)`.* 

'Class(f)', 'class(g)' and 'class(z)' values doesn`t matter for me.
I tried this:

```
> f<-"x^2"
> g<-"y^2"
> z<-f*g
```

I got:

```
Error in f * g : non-numeric argument to binary operator<br/>
```

I tried multiplying `f<-expression(f)` and `g<-expression(g)` with no result.

I tried also:

```
> f<-function(x) x^2
> g<-function(y) y^2
> z<-function(x,y) f*g
> z<-parse(text=z)
```

I got:

```
Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

With `paste(z)` instead of `parse(z)`:

```
> paste(z)
Error in paste(z) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

*Is there a way to do symbolic arithmetics with equations in R without using heavy software like yacas?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
f <- expression(x^2)
g <- expression(y^2)
z <- expression(eval(f) * eval(g))
#> eval(z,list(x = 1, y = 2))
#[1] 4
#...and here's another test, just to be sure:
#> identical(eval(z, list(x = 17, y = 21)), 17^2 * 21^2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or you could use the `rSymPy` package:

```
library(rSymPy)
x <- Var("x")
y <- Var("y")
sympy("f = x**2")
sympy("g = y**2")
sympy("z = f * g")
#> sympy("z")
#[1] "x**2*y**2"
#> sympy("z.subs([(x,3),(y,2)])")
#[1] "36"
```

This second suggestion might not be very attractive since it may be easier to use `Python` directly.

Comment: How can i extract from z `"(x^2)*(y^2)"`, `function(x,y) (x^2)*(y^2)` or (x^2)*(y^2) such that class((x^2)*(y^2))=call?

Comment: Working on it, but I'm not sure I can help any further here.

Comment: my best attempt was : `f <- expression(x^2); g <- expression(y^2);z<- paste("(",f,")","*","(",g,")"); z`

Comment: Yes, I tried to go down that road, too... or something similar. To no avail. ;-) I hope that one of the answers will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of symbols and functions is very confusing. If you want to use "pieces" of language objects, you would use something more like

```
f <- quote(x^2)
g <- quote(y^2)
z <- quote(f*g)
do.call("substitute", list(z, list(f=f, g=g)))
# x^2 * y^2
```

If you just want some form of functional composition, just make sure you are treating your variables like functions

```
f <- function(x) x^2
g <- function(y) y^2
z <- function(x,y) f(x)*g(y)
```

But these are just methods of building R language elements. It's not wise to think of these as algebraic manipulations. R will make no attempt to simplify or anything like that.